# Loading data from a program

Tags: r, dataset, package

I am trying to access a set of data which is part of a program. The result is the statement that the data does not exist. The code I am using follows:

> library(survival)

Loading required package: splines

> data(package="survival")
>
> data(aml)

Warning message:
In data(aml) : data set ‘aml’ not found

The command data(package="survival") produces a list of data including aml, yet the data(aml) command does make the data available. Am I missing a required command, or is it possible that there is a problem with the file of the survival package? How could I find the files and test the aml existence?

I have tested this for data files aml and am1 to make sure I did not misread the text. Neither one worked. According to the description in the list of data files, the name of this data file is all letters.

Comment: use `data(leukemia)` UPDATE: I can't confirm that it's the same as `aml` ...

Comment: it's there, just type `aml`

Comment: Just typing aml works. It produces the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of `survival`, the package authors have implemented `lazyData`, which means you can access the data without needing to call `data`, it can be found on the search path already.

```
library(survival)
exists('aml')
## [1] TRUE

head(aml)
  time status          x
1    9      1 Maintained
2   13      1 Maintained
3   13      0 Maintained
4   18      1 Maintained
5   23      1 Maintained
6   28      0 Maintained
```